# How can I call a variab that I wrote in a non-Class place to another class?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, weather-api

1.The "address" variable here gives me a city name with coordinates.I would like to write this address instead of Istanbul in the retrofit so that it can automatically show the weather of the selected location on the map.(Googlemap)

```
private const val TAG = "MapViewFragment"
class MapViewFragment: Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    companion object{
        private lateinit var nMap: GoogleMap

        var address:String = ""
        var test:String = ""
        var test2:String = ""

        var cacik:String = "adana"

        private var markers:MutableList<Marker> = mutableListOf<Marker>()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        map_view.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        map_view.onResume()
        map_view.getMapAsync(this)
        setToolbar()
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {

        if (map != null) {
            nMap = map
        }

        map?.let {
            nMap = it

            nMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener { markerToDelete ->
                Log.i(TAG, "onWindowsClickListener - Delete Thismarker")
                markers.remove(markerToDelete)
                markerToDelete.remove()
            }


            nMap.setOnMapLongClickListener { latlng ->

                Log.i(TAG, "onMapLongClickListener" + latlng)

                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "this is toast message" + latlng,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                showAlertDialog(latlng)



                address= getAddress(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)
                test = getAddress(37.000000,35.321335)
                test2 = "istanbul"


                Log.d(TAG,"test5 $address ${latlng.latitude} ${latlng.longitude}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"test"+address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun getAddress(lat: Double, lng: Double): String {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(requireContext())
        val list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1)
        return list[0].getAddressLine(0)
        //val stateName: String = addresses[0].getAddressLine(1)
    }

    private fun showAlertDialog(latlng: LatLng) {
        val dialog =
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setTitle("Create a marker").setMessage("add marker...")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .show()

        dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
            val marker = nMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("my new marker").snippet(
                    "a cool snippet"
                )
            )
            markers.add(marker)

            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapviewfragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    private fun setToolbar(){
        val actionBar : ActionBar? =(requireActivity() as MainActivity).supportActionBar
        actionBar?.apply {
            title = getString(R.string.Kartenansicht)
            setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
            setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

3.i just want to call "address" in my retrofit response .I want to call the address on the other class and write the location of Istanbul.The getter and setter methods don't work because I haven't written them inside the class.How can I use the address in another class.

```
private const val TAG = "Retrofit Connection"


fun main(){
    retrofitResponse()

}

object RetrofitSetup {

    //var test = MapViewFragment.address
    var urlAll = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}"
    var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
    val apiKey = "d459f98ffa705ad3f6c5e02f86d9fab9"

}

fun retrofitResponse(){

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RetrofitSetup.url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val weatherApi = retrofit.create(CallWeatherApi::class.java)
    val weatherResponseCall = weatherApi.getWeather(MapViewFragment.test,RetrofitSetup.apiKey)


    weatherResponseCall!!.enqueue(object : Callback<CurrentWeatherResponse?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<CurrentWeatherResponse?>, response: Response<CurrentWeatherResponse?>
        ) {
            if (response.code() == 404) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Successfuly")
            } else if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Error")
            }

            val mydata = response.body()
            val main = mydata!!.main
            val temp = main!!.temp
            val pres =main!!.pressure
            val temperature = (temp!! - 273.15).toInt()
            Log.d("TAG","City pressure :" + pres)
            Log.d("TAG","City Temp : " + temperature)


        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CurrentWeatherResponse?>, t: Throwable) {}
    })
}
```

[if i write default istanbul.its working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY0T2.png)

[if i create another varible in other class dosent work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcvDu.png)

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skXri.png)

Comment: where is "address" defined?

Comment: i did upgrade.its global.private lateinit var address:String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put "retrofitResponse" inside "RetrofitSetup" and add a parameter for the addresss

```
object RetrofitSetup {
    private const val urlAll = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}"
    private const val url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
    private const val apiKey = "keep this private"
    fun retrofitResponse(address: String) {
        ...
        val weatherResponseCall = weatherApi.getWeather(address, apiKey)
        ...
    }
}
```

then pass the address as argument

```
nMap.setOnMapLongClickListener { latlng ->
    val address = getAddress(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)
    RetrofitSetup.retrofitResponse(address)
}
```

Comment: its not working.Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property address has not been initialized

Comment: that is because you are trying to read it before set any value

Comment: i didnt understand.Should i create any another variable like this                                           "var test = MapViewFragment.address" Can you explain a little more, this is very important :) ty

Comment: if i change it for example "address = "istanbul".and if i take it from other class than coming same exception.What is diffrent.                                                                                 val weatherResponseCall = weatherApi.getWeather("istanbul" ,RetrofitSetup.apiKey)

Comment: this var `lateinit var address: String` will be empty until you give it a value. In this case you set the value on `OnMapLongClickListener`. So you cant call `retrofitResponse` before that

Comment: lateinit var cacik:String     cacik = "london"   i changed variable its now a city name.But after call "cacik " coming same exception.      Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cacik has not been initialized

Comment: if you have a default value then remove the `lateinit` keyword and just use `var address = "london"`

Comment: i cant yes its working if i write var address = "london". But i have to use it in google map onMapReady. for example address= getAddress(37.000000,35.321335) its giving to me a String City Name.but i cant define it ,If i write "lateinit var address" coming exception. var address:String = "" exception.var address:String
            get() {
                TODO()
            }
            set(value) {} exception.

Comment: where are you calling `retrofitResponse()`? the call should be inside `setOnMapLongClickListener`

Comment: i have 2 classes one RetrofirSetup and second MapViewFragment.After a longclick on map iam taking a String Cityname from long and lat.And iam trying to send this Address(City name ) to Retrofitsetup class.Should i defiend my retrofitResponse in **setOnMapLongClickListener**?

Comment: edit your question and show the "RetrofitSetup" class

Comment: did edit again and you can see there my test var.There is default coordinats and its not null anymore but iam taking exception.And check the photos pls

Comment: okay wow its working now thank you tooo much !!!!!!